# Artwork for iOS

Tags: ios, artwork

This may be an old and trivial question but I have been struggling to find out which tool should I use to create the artwork (icons, images, logos etc) for my iOS apps? Can somebody here share their first hand experience and suggest some tools (preferably free) to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever tool you use, be sure to design your artwork using vectors - iOS requires graphic assets in a variety of sizes, and you don't want to design, say, an app icon and realize later that you need a larger one, but have to redo your icon because your source wasn't a vector. After all, you never know when Apple might need a new size (for example, the new iPad and the retina sized splash screens).

Personally, I use photoshop to do my graphic work - mainly because it is a standard, though as long as your tool can generate pngs and jpgs, you should be fine. Just be sure it can handle scaling/zooming large images well as an iPad retina screenshot is 2048x1536 and it is unlikely your monitor will be ale to display it natively.

Comment: Thans Kerri. Can you please suggest me how do you change the size of generated vector image? I generated 57x57 px image and I tried to reduce the size to 20x20, it all messed up. I tried to change using Opacity.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use Inkscape and the GIMP, they are the open source equivalents for Illustrator and Photoshop even though they're not so equivalent.

Inkscape can generate PNG files which are good for IOS development.

Comment: This is a good answer, and @theiOSguy, I personally think that photoshop is the way to go (if you don't have a problem with the cost), but these are great alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are the most comfortable with. iOS can work with PNG, JPEG, GIF...

If you want to do it the professional way and/or you plan on interacting with other professionals on your project(s), then the standard is to use Photoshop and export UI assets as PNG files.

If you are looking to something similar at a more affordable price, Pixelmator is a popular tool with plenty of tutorials.